# An example of python code to connect to Google cloud memorystore memcached instance

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, memcached, google-apis-explorer

I want to connect to memorystore memcached instance with app engine and python3. I can't see any examples in internet :( How should the content of the app yaml file be and how can I connect to memorystore memcached instance with python? Also, how do I get and set data in a memcached instance?

Note : I don't want to use the memorystore redis instance because the query object does not acceptable in redis. Also I can't use app engine memcache because my project is python 3.8.

I'm waiting for your answers, thank you...